# Does the Bible admonish against "heterosexual" anal sex?

Tags: sexuality, homosexuality

The Bible admonishes against "sodomy" and "lying with a man as with a women?"

Is that a warning "only" against homosexuality? Or is it an admonition against anal sex, even between a man and a woman? How about oral sex?

I'm interested in an *overview* of the views of various Christian denominations on this matter, and what different sects might have to say.

Comment: I think the question is fine as it is now.  An overview is clearly invoked.

Comment: To the downvoters and/or close voters: The question is a Christian overview , so no particular perspective denomination is requested.

Answer (score 2):

By example, there are many, many instances of a man 'going in unto' a woman or 'knowing a woman' and the result being the conception of a child. There is not a single instance of the acts to which you refer, except there is a single hint, contained within a euphemism, that such acts might have occurred between those who forsook the Lord and worshipped idols.

Otherwise, within the pages of the bible, it is as though these acts do not occur between men and women.

As a Christian, I have been married twice and have had four children, two girls and two boys. I have never once even contemplated carrying out such acts in my marriage union.

It does not surprise me that I have been unable to find any material to quote regarding any kind of 'overview' of Christian opinion on these matters.

Comment: Romans 1:26  may hint at God’s displeasure with such unnatural acts

Comment: The context of Romans 1:26 is not the subject of this question. That is another subject altogether.

Comment: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/17467/11555.